# Getting the name of the current QGIS profile

Tags: pyqgis

How do I get the name (same a the directory name) of the current QGIS user profile in Python?

I found the [`QgsUserProfileManager`](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.30/core/QgsUserProfileManager.html) but it seems weird as I have to initialize it manually with the path to the profiles directory. This can't be right as the running QGIS should already know about that. But a web search did not yield anything obvious...

Calling `QgsUserProfileManager`'s [`userProfile`](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.30/core/QgsUserProfileManager.html#qgis.core.QgsUserProfileManager.userProfile) method gives me "None" altough the "default" profile is currently loaded.

```py
profiles_directory = Path(QgsApplication.qgisSettingsDirPath()).parent
profile_manager = QgsUserProfileManager(str(profiles_directory))
print(f"{profile_manager.allProfiles()=}")
# >>> profile_manager.allProfiles()=['a', 'b', 'foo', 'default']
print(profile_manager.userProfile())
# >>> None
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you look in QGIS 3.30 code what is done with `iface.userProfileManager()` you'll see :

```cpp
QgsUserProfileManager *QgisAppInterface::userProfileManager()
{
  return qgis->userProfileManager();
}
```

[*code reference*: qgisappinterface.cpp](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/final-3_30_3/src/app/qgisappinterface.cpp#L958)

This C++ code isn't present in the PyQGIS API.

So, in Python3, I have 2 workarounds :

- Get the base name of the QGIS settings directory path :

```py
import os

os.path.basename(
  os.path.normpath(
    QgsApplication.qgisSettingsDirPath()
  )
)
# >>> 'default'
```

- Load the `profiles.ini` file :

```py
import configparser

config = configparser.ConfigParser()
profiles_directory = Path(QgsApplication.qgisSettingsDirPath()).parent
config.read(f"{profiles_directory}/profiles.ini")
config["core"]["defaultProfile"]
# >>> 'default'
```

Comment: Thanks! I guess this is the best solution today as much as I dislike fiddling around with paths. :) Your second workaround is getting the default profile, not the active one I think?

Comment: When you change the profile, QGIS change the `"defaultProfile"` value in the ini and open a new instance of QGIS. So for me : current = default if you didn't change the profile in your session.

Answer (score 4):

In QGIS 3.30 onwards you can use `iface.userProfileManager().userProfile().name()`.

See https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.30/gui/QgisInterface.html#qgis.gui.QgisInterface.userProfileManager

Comment: I am looking for a nice solution for <3.30 though.

Answer (score -1):

Are you trying to get the username associated with the current QGIS session ?

This works for me

```
from getpass import getuser

# Get the username of the current user
username = getuser()

# Print the username
print("Current QGIS User Profile:", username)
```

Comment: The OP doesn't search the user name but the profile name (the QGIS base profile name is "default", you can see the current profile in the menu settings > user profiles).

Comment: Correct, I am looking for the profile name, not the user name. Thanks though!